# Angular calling an Array from a service method() to my main component ;

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, observable

In my **api-service.ts**
i have an array which contains some data in an Array.

```
 public getData():Observable<any[]>  {

    return  Observable.toString[ObsResult];
  }
```

Then in my main component i am trying to call getData() method to display data in
**main.componenet.html**

```
service.getData().subscribe({result => console.log (result)});
```

I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`

I am guessing this line is wrong but i am not sure what to put here
`Observable.toString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### There are multiple approaches you could use to solve the problem.

### Method 1: More Native implementation

```js
public getData(): Observable < any[] > {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    observer.next(ObsResult);
    observer.complete();
  });
}
```

### Method 2: Angular (rxjs) Implementation

```js
public getData(): Observable < any[] > {
  return of(ObsResult);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have static data

```
   example: const ObsResult = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

You can use

```
public getData():Observable<any[]>  {

    return  Observable.of(ObsResult);
}
```

then you can subscribe to

```
service.getData().subscribe({result => console.log (result)});
```